# use extrapolation to solve mousemove event lag

Tags: javascript, dom, mousemove, dom-events

After some search on this site I understand that I have no control over a browser's `mousemove` event frequency.

So I want to apply some kind of extrapolation method to solve the lagged `mousemove` event problem.

I record every mouse position when the `mousemove` event is triggered, and calculate the acceleration (make use of finite difference to get velocity, and then acceleration).

After that in the `render()` function, I measure the delta time elapsed from last `render()` function call.
Finally I extrapolate the position with acceleration and `dt`.

But I do not see any significant effect using this method. Is there anything wrong?

EDIT: I make a small running example here. (sorry for the unclear question statements)

https://gist.github.com/3858124

Comment: "But I do not see any significant effect using this method" - what are you trying to do with extrapolated position, exactly?

Comment: What are you doing with it, how are you calling your render method, what are you doing inside of it, how are you storing your measurements, how are you calculating them in regard to time-elapsed, what are you applying your force to, which makes you think that nothing's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after I paste my code on the gist I realize the problem and then fix the bug.

The problem is:

I use NDC coordinate to compute the derivative, while I use world space coordinate to do the extrapolation.

This is the new code:

https://gist.github.com/3858277

Conclusion:
There is some effect on the lagged `mouseevent`, but not so much. And as a (bad) side effect, there will be a over-shoot when your mouse movement makes an emergency braking.

I am still seeking a better solution. Any opinion/suggestion is welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll do any better with extrapolation. All current browsers maintain a single thread for javascript, which can be per-tab (Chrome) or per browser window (Firefox). So if you are doing work in your script, the brower will trigger no mousemove events at all while your script is running*.

So the best way to improve the mousemove update frequency is to optimise your other javascript to get out of the way of the mousemove events. One way is to use more asynchronous calls. So you could write your code to call `setTimeout(nextFunc, 0)` with the next step of a loop, which passes control back from your script and allows events to be triggered before the next step of your loop.

* The exception to the rule on single threads and synchronous calculation is WebWorkers, which allow you to do a certain set of things in parallel with the rest of the execution, largely those which do not involve the DOM.